# Confused about this compiler error in my react app

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone help me with what attempted import error means? Failed to compile.

`./src/modules/Dashboard/Dashboard.js`

```
Attempted import error: 'filterMenu' is not exported from '../Filters/action' (imported as 'filterActions')
```

this is the problem please help me solve it

My imports are like this:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as api from '../../shared/api.js';
import Cart from '../Cart/cart';
import * as filterActions from '../Filters/action';
import FilterMenu from "../Filters/FilterMenu";
import MenuItemList from '../Menu/menuItemList';
import * as actions from './action.js';
and this is my Filter menu file
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import FilterMenu as actions from './action.js';
import FilterOptions from "./FilterOptions";

const initialstate = {
  allItems: [],
  filteredItems: [],
  filterNameText: '',
  filterCategoryText: '',
  filterRatingText: '',
  filterPriceText: ''
};
```

Comment: Well, it looks like you're not exporting anything from FilterMenu. Can U share both files? Post them separately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `../Filters/action` file you will need to explicitly export "filterMenu"

Something like:

```
// action.js file
const filterMenu = () => <div>This is my filter menu</div>

export filterMenu
```

Alternatively you could use the "default export" like this:

```
// action.js file
const filterMenu = () => <div>This is my filter menu</div>

export default filterMenu
```